# Cordova File Download and open it using cordova

Tags: html, cordova, jquery-mobile

Please forgive my ignorance, Any advice/directional assistance would be greatly appreciated.

I have a small app that reads data from an API with json requests.
One of the actions the app needs to do is to download a given PDF and open it either in the app, or in the OS default viewer.

I have followed several guides, but I think I am not including all needed files or something. The guides don't speak of including files of any type, but I still get errors.

In [this link](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/#sample) for example I followed the steps, but I am getting an error when I add these two lines in to the script at the bottom of the page:

```
var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
console.log(FileTransfer);
```

When running that I get the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: FileTransfer is not defined at employee_documents.html:102`

I am sure that either i am not including the files correctly in netbeans or I am missing something simple...
Any advise would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The Cordova file-transfer plugin is deprecated. Have a look at this example code: https://cordova.apache.org/blog/2017/10/18/from-filetransfer-to-xhr2.html

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question specifically. In order to solve the error, you need to run the cordova app using the CLI. In that way, the plugins installed from your cordova will be used otherwise if you're only running it via refresh or something similar it will produce an error like this.

In other words, type this command in your CLI:

```
cordova run browser
```

You can change this to your preferred platform (android, ios)